# HTML5 local storage reverts after pressing navigating back

Tags: html, local-storage

I have this issue that I ran into today. I am making a mini-cart for website, it is going to be shown on every page except for the actual cart.

Performance on site is kind of important, so I've decided to temporary cache current items in the cart in local storage to avoid unnecessary server side request to fetch same items on every single page load.

Since mini cart is not actually displayed on cart, It still listens for callbacks, e.g. when removing an item. The point is to reset cache or delete just that item from the cached copy.

---

The issue I am facing:

User ends up in cart page, which might clear the cache ( if user is in last step )
if I he navigates to some other page by clicking a link, it works fine - cache is cleared.

Problem is that if I use back button ( browser back button, mouse back button etc. ) user goes back to previous page and the changes I made in cart page ( clearing cache ) are reverted! ( even when I reload page )

**So the question is:**

How do I clear the local storage and avoid it being restored if I go back? At the same time having consistent behavior in other browsers.

---

This `cache` is nothing more but an item is local storage, it is updated when new item is added or removed. Clearing the cache would simply delete it (using localStorage.removeItem).

Comment: How are you clearing the cache?

Comment: I've updated my question a bit

Comment: Can you write a quick function to actually check the local storage when you go back a page? Just do a loop on all L.S. items with an alert or something. I'm wondering if there wasn't some form of browser caching done which would result in the item not being in storage but where the page still appears as it was with the item displayed.

Comment: I don't have to do this, I can track local storage variables in chrome developer tools. Thing is that when I am in certain cart page, its empty ( because its cleared) and when I go back - old entries appear. It doesn't matter if I delete storage item completely or just update it.

Comment: And if you do CTRL+F5 on the "back" page? I'm just trying to figure out if the variables are cached by the browser with the page or if they are actually not deleted. I am starting to suspect that the browser caches them with the page to provide a consistent user experience.

Comment: No change with CTRL+F5. Its pretty weird, I have created 2 html( also checked with php extension) pages to test this and it works as I want it to work. But on the actual site - it doesn't it somehow gets restored, and it only happens when using back button. Could it be because of expire or no-cache header being set? or because of seo friendly urls ( like product/12/test or cart/overview )?

Comment: And if you type the url of the "back" page into the address bar instead of using the back button?

Comment: Then it works, just like clicking a link.

Comment: I've just tried in IE, IE8 in particular - works as it should.. No idea how to solve this as of now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that the item is removed when trying this in IE8, it is safe to say that you are executing the correct code to remove the item. I would then have to say that this looks like it is a browser-related issue, where the browser retains the information when you go back to maintain a consistent user experience. This appears to be supported by the fact that navigating directly to the same link does not restore the deleted object.

If you are going through a process like filling a shopping cart this may not matter, so long as once you leave the back trail of visited pages that the cache is updated correctly. (i.e. item 1 in the cache is deleted on page B, returns when going back to page A but disappears when navigating to page D).

The other option you have is to simply use a server-side session storage mechanism. This is by far what I would do. One of the biggest mistake that I see programmers, especially on SO, making is that they assume that operation X is going to impact performance and try to avoid it. **You cannot make any concrete statement about performance without benchmarking.** It is very possible that your server-side will be quicker than your cilent side code at returning a couple session objects. Server-side session is a fantastic tool used by virtually every site on the net and it would be unfortunate to ignore it because of a misplaced assumption about how it will impact performance.

Comment: The point of this cache in my case is that, I completely skip a server side call to get current items in the cart. That particular call is heavier than any other, as to get those items - browser has to connect to drupal powered site, which in turn connects to another API type server(powered by Zend and custom library) to retrieve the list of items. This project is of integration type, making shop on drupal part is not an option.

Comment: When you return to the former page with the back button you will more than likely get a cached version. That said, the point of SS cache in my response is that it is predictable... you don't have predictability with client-side cache. Here you will know what to expect and can make adjustments as necessary. Not to mention the fact that users are used to there being little quirks when navigating back through a process... even Amazon has them--if you can give your users a predictable experience they will generally be better off than an unpredictable one.

Comment: It would be fine by me like this, but thing is that when it reverts this way, user would be presented with possibly incorrect cached version, that would remain this way, even when he continues browsing, until eventually it would get invalidated. Ill have to debug this bit more, maybe Ill find a way.

Comment: Like I said even Amazon has this problem if you back up when you change your cart. It isn't a perfect solution I agree but users will generally expect this to happen. At any rate, if they see their cart has an extra item they will go to the cart and when they do the data displayed will be correct. If the behaviour is predictable then there will be less confusion than if it differs from browser to browser.